# how to create a custom push notification template using ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need to customize the push notification template for my ionic 3 app. I know it can be done in a native android app but I have not been able to find how to do it in a hybrid app. Is it even possible to implement this feature?

Comment: Do you want to customize in App notification of Tray notification?

Comment: i am not sure what is a tray notification. i want to change the template of how a push notification for my app like adding a background color, adding image etc

Comment: @RahulCv do u have any solution regarding this?

Comment: Yes will update in some time